# R - How to do Python's Try Except

Tags: r, exception

I'm starting to work with R. Although I'm more used to python.

I want to do a script in R that uses the library MASS. I though about doing a Try, Except to see if the library exists, otherwise install it.
Something like this:

```
Try:
    library("MASS")
Except SomeError:
    install.packages("MASS")
    library("MASS")
```

Or perhaps in R this doesn't make much sense.
Anyway any suggestions is welcome :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `require` is virtually identical to `library`, except it returns a logical value.

```
> x <- require("MASS")
> x
[1] TRUE

> x <- require("notExist")
Loading required package: notExist
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'notExist'
> x
[1] FALSE
```

This means you can use a simple `if` statement, something like:

```
if(!require("MASS")) install.packages("MASS")
```

---

R also has an error capturing mechanism.  Read about it at `?try` or `?tryCatch`